# Serializing a manually written code

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, serialization, client-server

I am having a problem receiving files from the client. Someone suggested that I should use binary serialization to send and receive messages in stream. Can you give me ideas on how I should serialize this? I just learned about serialization not long ago so I am quite confused on how I should associate it with my program.

This is the client that 'should' be serialize

```
 public void sendthedata()
        {
            if (!_timer.Enabled) // If timer is not running send data and start refresh interval
            {
                SendData();
                _timer.Enabled = true;
            }
            else // Stop timer to prevent further refreshing
            {
                _timer.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
        private List<int> listedProcesses = new List<int>();
        private void SendData()
        {
            String processID = "";
            String processName = "";
            String processPath = "";
            String processFileName = "";
            String processMachinename = "";

            listBox1.BeginUpdate();
            try
            {   
                piis = GetAllProcessInfos();
                for (int i = 0; i < piis.Count; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (!listedProcesses.Contains(piis[i].Id)) //placed this on a list to avoid redundancy
                        {
                            listedProcesses.Add(piis[i].Id);
                            processID = piis[i].Id.ToString();
                            processName = piis[i].Name.ToString();
                            processPath = piis[i].Path.ToString();
                            processFileName = piis[i].FileName.ToString();
                            processMachinename = piis[i].Machinename.ToString();
                            output.Text += "\n\nSENT DATA : \n\t" + processFileName + "\n\t" + processMachinename + "\n\t" + processID + "\n\t" + processName + "\n\t" + processPath + "\n";
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        wait.Abort();
                        output.Text += "Error..... " + ex.StackTrace;

                    }

                    NetworkStream ns = tcpclnt.GetStream();
                    String data = "";
                    data = "--++" + processFileName + " " +  processMachinename + " "  + processID + " " + processPath;
                    if (ns.CanWrite)
                    {
                        byte[] bf = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(data);
                        ns.Write(bf, 0, bf.Length);
                        ns.Flush();
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                listBox1.EndUpdate();
            } 
        }
```

And deserializing in the server

```
private void recieveData()
    {
        NetworkStream nStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        ASCIIEncoding ascii = null;
        while (!stopRecieving)
        {
            if (nStream.CanRead)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                nStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
                recvDt = ascii.GetString(buffer);
                /*Received message checks if it has +@@+ then the ip is disconnected*/
                bool f = false;
                f = recvDt.Contains("+@@+");
                if (f)
                {
                    string d = "+@@+";
                    recvDt = recvDt.TrimStart(d.ToCharArray());
                    clientDis();
                    stopRecieving = true;
                }

                //else if (recvDt.Contains("^^"))
                //{
                //    new Transmit_File().transfer_file(file, ipselected);
                //}
                /* ++-- shutsdown/restrt/logoff/abort*/
                else if (recvDt.Contains("++--"))
                {
                    string d = "++--";
                    recvDt = recvDt.TrimStart(d.ToCharArray());
                    this.Invoke(new rcvData(addToOutput));
                    clientDis();
                }
                /*--++ Normal msg*/
                else if (recvDt.Contains("--++"))
                {
                    string d = "--++";
                    recvDt = recvDt.TrimStart(d.ToCharArray());
                    this.Invoke(new rcvData(addToOutput));

                }
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

    }

    public void addToOutput()
    {
        if (recvDt != null && recvDt != "")
        {

            output.Text += "\n Received Data : " + recvDt;
            recvDt = null;


        }

    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of rules to follow when serialising a piece of data.
It's easy to convert data to bytes, but consider how to reconstruct the data on the other side. Assume that the server can't have any knowledge on what you sended.

In your serialiser you just convert a couple of strings into a byte[] and send it over. Example:

```
string x = "abcdef";
string y = "ghijk";

var bytes = Encoding.Ascii.GetBytes(x + y);
```

the server receives: `"abcdefghijk"`;

Is it possible for the server to determine and reconstruct strings x and y?
Since the server has no knowledge of the length of either x and y: no.

There are ways to solve this:

1. Use fixed length fields. In my example x should always be 6 chars and y should always be 5 chars in length. decoding on the server then becomes as trivial as

   string x = data.Substring(0, 6)
   string y = data.Substring(6, 5)
2. Use delimiters between the fields. If you are familiar with cvs, the ',' splits the fields. This however has it drawbacks, how to handle a ',' somewhere in a string? The data send over would be like "`abcdef,ghijk`"
3. Send the size of each field before the content of the field.
   A naive approach just to clarify: string x would be send as '`6abcdef`' and y as '`5ghijk`'

Doing all this things by hand can get really hairy and is something that I would consider only if really needed.

I would resort to existing frameworks that do an excellent job on this subject:

[Json.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

[protobuf ported by Jon skeet](http://protobuf-csharp-port)

In this case I would first create a class to define the data send to the server instead of a bunch of strings:

```
class ProcessInfo{
    public string ProcessID {get;set;}
    public string ProcessName {get;set;}
    public string ProcessPath {get;set;}
    public string ProcessFileName {get;set;}
    public string ProcessMachinename {get;set;}
};
```

the using Json to serialise this:

```
var procinfo = new ProcessInfo{
                   ProcessId = "1",
                   ...
               };
var serialised = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(procinfo);
var bytes = Encoding.Utf8.GetBytes(serialised);
ns.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

And restore it on the server just by:

```
var procInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProcessInfo>(json);
```

Comment: will json be a different file?

Comment: is there a namespace for json or it can be coded directly to the windows form?

Comment: How about using nuget: Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: hmm.. i really have no idea about json but ill look into it.